# Extend a Host Named Site Collection for anonymous access SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, host-named

Our Intranet is made up of multiple Host Named Site Collections e.g.

```
Intranet.mycompany.com, 
ICT.mycompany.co.uk, 
finance.mycompany.co.uk.
```

for different parts of it.

The idea was to give each section its own identity that people could go to it directly if they wanted.

Now a decision has been made that they want to serve up the content of these sites to 3rd parties as well, but anonymously.

So easy I thought just Extend the web application in Central Admin on another port, and setup for Anonymous in the sites.

But this doesn't work with host named site collections, even if you add bindings to the web site or Alternative Access Mappings, all you get is the root site (same as server name in our case), and that doesn't have a site template.

I've spent 2 days so far looking for an answer, I've read a lot about setting up host names site collections, and general discussions e.g.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx

Found less on extending them for anonymous access, I've seen snippets of commands for this and that, but none of it gives enough context to understand, and it doesn't help that its already been promised to happen by a certain date, before I was asked to look into it.

Is that even possible in SharePoint 2010, and if so can anyone give some advice on the method and Powershell commands for doing this?

Comment: I've just found this URL - http://dinushaonline.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/extend-sharepoint-host-named-site.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying to Extend Host Named Site Collection to use a different authentication method does not appear to be possible in SharePoint 2010 but can be done in SharePoint 2013, the answer appears to be upgrade to 2013.

The Set-SpSiteUrl powershell command doesn't exist in SharePoint 2010 and this site (below) suggests upgrading to 2013 to achieve this

http://dinushaonline.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/extend-sharepoint-host-named-site.html

In this website see the paragraph under 'Can I Use Alternate Access Mappings with Host Named Site Collections?'

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx